# treecolumn renderer with icon - extjs 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I'm building simple application using Ext Scheduler (http://www.bryntum.com/products/scheduler/).
I'm trying to add custom renderer for treecolumn that will have icon of person in tree.
[image]

I've created rendered for that column:

```
renderer: function (v, m, r) {
            if (r.get('leaf')) {
                return '<div style="float: left">' +
                    r.get('Name') +
                    '</div>'+
                    '<img data-qtip="<img src=iconUrl.png width=60px height=60px/>" '+
                    'src="iconUrl.png" '+
                    'width="20px" height="20px" style="float: right; margin-right: 5px"/>';
            }
            return v;
        }
```

This looks OK, but for long names I get unwanted look:

[image]

Looking thrue code I found some unwanted markup:
[image]

What I need is almost identical renderer as in standard treecolumn, but I need to add extra icon on right of that column - employee image thumbnail.

[image]

I was searching over docs and I found out that there is private property called `cellTpl` (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Column2.html#Ext-tree-Column)

but I don't know how should I change this and should I change this at all because it is marked as private on top.

How should I change that renderer to get effect as on last image?

Here is some jsfiddle to play: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/gwFdr/

Comment: I am also struck with this similar question. I do not like to use render to add some div inside span which is not recommended to add block element inside a text element

Comment: @naren I solved my problem by creating custom tree column that shows images instead of leaf icons. I'll post my code right away :)

Comment: Thanks for posting code. My scenario is little complicated as I need to register event on the icon and when clicked on icon I should not  event propagation. I felt actioncolumn would better server my purpose. I found nice writeup here on using actioncolumn http://www.learnsomethings.com/2011/09/25/the-new-extjs4-xtype-actioncolumn-in-a-nutshell/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended extending `Ext.tree.Column` to instead of normal leaf icons it shows thumbnails.
Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('Grafik.component.tree.Column2', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Column',
    alias: 'widget.treecolumn2',

    thumbnailsServiceUrl:'',

    cellTpl: [
        '<tpl for="lines">',
            '<img src="{parent.blankUrl}" class="{parent.childCls} {parent.elbowCls}-img ',
            '{parent.elbowCls}-<tpl if=".">line<tpl else>empty</tpl>"/>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<img src="{blankUrl}" class="{childCls} {elbowCls}-img {elbowCls}',
            '<tpl if="isLast">-end</tpl><tpl if="expandable">-plus {expanderCls}</tpl>"/>',
        '<tpl if="checked !== null">',
            '<input type="button" role="checkbox" <tpl if="checked">aria-checked="true" </tpl>',
                'class="{childCls} {checkboxCls}<tpl if="checked"> {checkboxCls}-checked</tpl>"/>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<img src="{loginUrl}" class="{childCls} {baseIconCls} ',
            '{baseIconCls}-<tpl if="leaf">leaf<tpl else>parent</tpl> {iconCls}"',
            '<tpl if="icon">style="background-image:url({icon})"</tpl>/>',
        '<tpl if="href">',
            '<a href="{href}" target="{hrefTarget}" class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</a>',
        '<tpl else>',
            '<span class="{textCls} {childCls}">{value}</span>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],


    treeRenderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
        var me = this,
            cls = record.get('cls'),
            renderer = me.origRenderer,
            data = record.data,
            parent = record.parentNode,
            rootVisible = view.rootVisible,
            lines = [],
            parentData;

        if (cls) {
            metaData.tdCls += ' ' + cls;
        }

        while (parent && (rootVisible || parent.data.depth > 0)) {
            parentData = parent.data;
            lines[rootVisible ? parentData.depth : parentData.depth - 1] =
                    parentData.isLast ? 0 : 1;
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }

        return me.getTpl('cellTpl').apply({
            record: record,
            baseIconCls: me.iconCls,
            iconCls: data.iconCls,
            icon: data.icon,
            checkboxCls: me.checkboxCls,
            checked: data.checked,
            elbowCls: me.elbowCls,
            expanderCls: me.expanderCls,
            textCls: me.textCls,
            leaf: data.leaf,
            expandable: record.isExpandable(),
            isLast: data.isLast,
            blankUrl: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL,
            loginUrl: data.leaf ? me.thumbnailsServiceUrl + record.get('Login') : Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL,
            href: data.href,
            hrefTarget: data.hrefTarget,
            lines: lines,
            metaData: metaData,
            // subclasses or overrides can implement a getChildCls() method, which can
            // return an extra class to add to all of the cell's child elements (icon,
            // expander, elbow, checkbox).  This is used by the rtl override to add the
            // "x-rtl" class to these elements.
            childCls: me.getChildCls ? me.getChildCls() + ' ' : '',
            value: renderer ? renderer.apply(me.origScope, arguments) : value
        });
    }
});
```

And usage looks like this:

```
{
    text: 'Users',
    dataIndex: 'Name',
    hideable: false,
    width: 260,
    xtype: 'treecolumn2',
    sortable: true,
    resizable: false,
    thumbnailsServiceUrl: window.appUrl + 'api/Thumbnails/'
}
```

Where `api/Thumbnails` is service that takes login and returns image.
Simple solution, hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Maybe for your scenario if it is just displaying icon you can change the in css by using the .{chilcls}.{txtCls} selector or you can you the renderer like in your question to add a new span with css for image and provide display:inline-block for the image css